# Retrieving the value of button while submitting form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file index.php with a log in form comprising a field for the email address, a field for the password, a box to check, and two submit buttons:

- the first button ("log_in") is for trying to log in with the current combination email/password. This button triggers a script ("check_box()") which verifies that the box has been checked.
- the second button is for generating a new password for the current email address. It also triggers a script ("confirmation()") which asks the user to confirm before executing the action.

I am trying to submit the form with javascript, and to keep track of which button has been submitted in order to execute the correct action. Please see the code below.

```
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address" />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="radio" id="box" name="box"><label for="box">Please check this box if you want to log in.</label>
        <input type="button" id="log_in" name="log_in" value="Log in" onclick="return check_box();"/>
        <input type="button" id="change_password" name="change_password" value="Password forgotten?" onclick="return confirmation();"/>
    </form>
```

```js
function confirmation(){
 if (!confirm("A new password will be generated and sent to your email address. Please make sure that your email address is written correctly, and click on Confirm to proceed.")) {
  return FALSE;
 }
 else{
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.submit();
 }
}

function check_box(){
 var success = document.querySelector("input[name=box]:checked");
 if(!success){
  alert("Please check the box.");
  }
 else{
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.submit();     
  }
}
```

My problem is to retrieve the values of the buttons when the form is submitted. I tried

```
if(isset($_POST['log_in']))
```

to detect whether the user has been trying to log in, and

```
if(isset($_POST['change_password']))
```

to detect whether the user wants to change password. But these tests always return FALSE. Where is the mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure an input of type `button` can work with what you're trying to accomplish. Have you tried changing it to `type="submit"`?

Comment: @Jeto Thank you. The tests work if I use submit instead of button, but the problem is that the form will then be submitted in all cases, even if the user does not check the box before trying to log in.

Comment: Try having your functions return false then. To be honest this isn't the cleanest way of doing things though (overall, not this point in particular).

Comment: @Jeto Thank you again. Would you mind elaborating a bit on your comment and show me a better way? I would be happy to learn how to do things properly.

Comment: Sure. For a start, a better way of capturing events is to make use of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (this is the reference, you can find more basic examples online), instead of inline `on<event>` attributes. In that case, you'd use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent your form from submitting automatically.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a side: If you are new to javascript, you could also look into the jquery library which turns a lot of this verbose javascript code into very short and easy methods.

Comment: @IncredibleHat How do you know I am new to javascript? :-) Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Well ;) ... I was new to javascript for about 15 years, then I threw my hands up and got lost in jquery. Now I can't get enough of it =D